# Where can i get am335x microcontroller board registers header file?

Tags: cpu-registers, atmel, texas-instruments

Hi i was previously using the atmel at91 microcontroller and for all the register values i was refering the foolowing header files Linux/atmel_serial.h and linux/atmel_pdc.h.
Now i have shifted to an Texas Instruments devgeloper board which is using am335x processor so i want to know where i can find the same relavent files for this instrument.
The list of registers that i am using in my code when i was working on the atmel board was

```
ATMEL_PDC_RPR
ATMEL_PDC_RCR
ATMEL_PDC_TPR
ATMEL_PDC_TCR
ATMEL_PDC_TNPR
ATMEL_PDC_TNCR
ATMEL_PDC_PTCR
ATMEL_PDC_TXTEN
ATMEL_US_CR
ATMEL_US_TXEN
ATMEL_US_RXDIS
ATMEL_US_IER
ATMEL_US_TXEMPTY
ATMEL_US_RXRDY
ATMEL_PDC_RXTEN
ATMEL_US_RTOR
ATMEL_US_TIMEOUT
ATMEL_US_OVRE
ATMEL_US_FRAME
ATMEL_US_PARE
ATMEL_US_RSTSTA
ATMEL_PDC_RXTDIS
ATMEL_US_RETTO
ATMEL_US_STTTO
ATMEL_US_CSR
ATMEL_US_IDR
ATMEL_US_TXDIS
ATMEL_US_RXEN
ATMEL_PDC_TXTDIS
ATMEL_US_MR
ATMEL_US_USCLKS
ATMEL_US_CHRL
ATMEL_US_NBSTOP
ATMEL_US_PAR
ATMEL_US_USCLKS_MCK_DIV8
ATMEL_US_CHRL_8
ATMEL_US_NBSTOP_1
ATMEL_US_PAR_NONE
ATMEL_US_IMR
ATMEL_US_BRGR
ATMEL_PDC_RNPR
ATMEL_PDC_RNCR
ATMEL_US_RSTRX
ATMEL_US_RSTTX
PDC_RX_TIMEOUT
ATMEL_US_USMODE_RS485
ATMEL_US_TXRDY
```

I need the equivalent for the TI am335x development board.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the device datasheet for device registers:
http://www.ti.com/litv/pdf/spruh73i

In Linux each device driver has it's own internal definitions of registers for which it has appropriate access rights. There is no unique place which defines all peripheral registers like Atmel does.